# Gtk: Webkit WebView C++ (can't load url + awkward terminal output)

Tags: application-development, gtk, c++, glade

I am trying to include a webkit webview within my c++ application.
My project uses Glade ui, and I embedded webview into a scrolled window.

What I do not understand at all is this awkward output + the url is not loaded:

```
zubozrout@frozenlinux:~/Downloads/Devel/ssm4/usr/bin$ g++ ssm.cpp -o steamskinmanager `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs webkitgtk-3.0` && ./steamskinmanager

No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.58.9, x4, 2401Mhz, 9447MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.58.9, x4, 2401Mhz, 9447MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:013] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:013] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:014] Cpu: 6.58.9, x4, 2401Mhz, 9447MB
[000:014] Computer model: Not available
[000:014] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:014] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:014] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:013] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:013] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:014] Cpu: 6.58.9, x4, 2401Mhz, 9447MB
[000:014] Computer model: Not available
```

Here is the webview part of my code:

```
builder = gtk_builder_new ();
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "ui.glade", NULL);
window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
```

`[...]`

```
GObject* webview_help;
webview_help = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "webview_help");
WebKitWebView *webview = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());

gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(webview_help), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
g_object_ref_sink(G_OBJECT(webview));
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(webview_help), GTK_WIDGET(webview));
webkit_web_view_load_uri(webview, "http://www.google.com");
g_object_unref(webview);
```

Unfortunately, there are not many tutorials describing gtk webview usage. As an inspiration, I used [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/WebKitGtk/ProgrammingGuide/Tutorial) (it it probable I missed something). Sadly, I can't find the solution to my problem.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry - it was simple yet I was not able to find out what is causing it.
The answer is not to forget to show the webview widget.

```
gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(webview));
```

But I still have the awkward terminal output that I would like to get rid of.

Comment: It may be vital to say the strange console output is caused by this function: `webkit_web_view_load_uri(webview, "http://www.google.com");`